# LibGDX ASNE gradle integration - import cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to integrate ASNE in my libGDX project. I added the following lines to every 'project(":android/core/desktop/html/ios")' block inside it's 'dependencies' block:

```
compile 'com.github.asne:asne-facebook:0.3.3'
compile 'com.github.asne:asne-twitter:0.3.3'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

So, as an example the project(":core") block looks like this:

```
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.asne:asne-facebook:0.3.3'
        compile 'com.github.asne:asne-twitter:0.3.3'
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
```

When trying to import one of it's classes, I get an "The import com.github cannot be resolved" error:

```
import com.github.gorbin.asne.core.SocialNetwork;
```

How can I use the classes from ASNE?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse: `Project > Clean`.